# Is there an established or agreed pattern or algorithm for creating a 'recommended for you' list from user history data?

Tags: database, algorithm, search

In creating a content sharing site, is there an agreed or typical pattern or algorithm for analyzing user history and recommending new, unseen content?

I would like the answer to be language agnostic, but if it matters, it would be PHP/mySQL.

Current data tracked is:

- Likes/dislikes (user A likes content B, user A dislikes content B)
- Content has related mapping (so content A, is related to content B, C and D)
- There is no relationship between users (no friends/etc)

Ideally I would like to counteract aging content, so newer content is weight higher.

Comment: As far as I know, this era is under active research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution found via research was an implementation of Slope One within mysql.

Please see here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope_One